# Handlebars syntax issue with JSON from Trello API

Tags: asp.net, jquery, handlebars.js, trello, trello.net

Struggling with my Handlebars syntax for JSON data when returned from the Trello.Net wrapper for the Trello API. I'm doing a card search for some string which returns cards. This part works well. However, wrapping my Handlebars HTML with {{#each}} throws a 'n is undefined' error in the handlebars core file.

Here's my JSON:

```
"[ 
    { "Id": "519a423c4bedcac656000a84", 
      "Name": "sdvsdv", 
      "Desc": "**Submitted by me**\r\n\r\nsdvsdvsdvsdv", 
      "Other keys": "Other values",
 }, 
    { "Id": "519a423c4bedcac656000a84", 
      "Name": "sdvsdv", 
      "Desc": "**Submitted by me**\r\n\r\nsdvsdvsdvsdv", 
      "Other keys": "Other values",
 }.. and so on 
]"
```

Here's my (stripped down) Handlebars template:

```
 <script id="resultsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each}}
    <div class="result {{Id}}">
        <h3>{{Name}}</h3>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

and my Ajax call:

```
 $(".search-btn").click(function () {
         var data = 'David Orriell';
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "SearchYourCards.aspx/GetCards",
             data: "{'data': '" + data + "'}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (msg) {
                 var res = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                 var source = $('#resultsTemplate').html();
                 var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                 var context = res;
                 $('#results').html(template(context));
                 //$('#results').accordion({ header: ".result h3" });
             }
         });
     });
```

My HTML template is always empty. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your error console. Then you should tell `{{#each}}` what you want to iterate over:

```
{{#each this}}
    <!-- ... -->
{{/each}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vcQdf/

Comment: The only error in the console was 'TypeError: n is undefined' in handlebars.js.

However, using {{#each this}} has solved my issue.

Thanks,